# How to count average for most numbers excluding very big numbers?

Tags: average

I have such values:

```
Video №1 = 277811 views = 2.4915%
Video №2 = 980423 views = 8.7927%
Video №3 = 33940 views = 0.3044%
Video №4 = 177805 views = 1.5946%
Video №5 = 71010 views = 0.6368%
Video №6 = 224101 views = 2.0098%
Video №7 = 64721 views = 0.5804%
Video №8 = 5364 views = 0.0481%
Video №9 = 627 views = 0.0056%
Video №10 = 2563 views = 0.023%
Video №11 = 165315 views = 1.4826%
Video №12 = 495 views = 0.0044%
Video №13 = 8304189 views = 74.474%
Video №14 = 165151 views = 1.4811%
Video №15 = 3981 views = 0.0357%
Video №16 = 246518 views = 2.2108%
Video №17 = 6783 views = 0.0608%
Video №18 = 78511 views = 0.7041%
Video №19 = 341145 views = 3.0595%
==
Views total = 11150453
Views average = views total / 19 videos = 586866
```

With what formula I can exclude big values "`Video №13 = 8304189 views = 74.474%`", "`Video №2 = 980423 views = 8.7927%`"?

I know I could use such formula like:

```
if(video views >= than 5%) so exclude it
```

But what to do in that situation:

```
Video №1 = 1000 views = 10%
Video №2 = 3000 views = 30%
Video №3 = 2000 views = 20%
Video №4 = 4000 views = 40%
==
Views total = 10000
Views avarage = views total / 4 videos = 2500
```

In that situation there is no need to exclude any values, but with formula:

```
if(video views >= than 5%) so exclude it
```

4 videos will be excluded

Answer (score 0):

You have to decide what you want.  There is a formula for what you want if you know what it is.  You could exclude the top five videos.  You could exclude the top $10\%$.  You could compute the mean and standard deviation and exclude any one that is two or three standard deviations high.

Comment: Thank you for ideas, I found formula that I need, if there is 3 videos: 100% / 3 videos =  33.33% maximum limit, for 20 videos = 100% / 20 = 5%

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to do “compute the average, except in a way that’s robust to outliers” is the median.